# Minimize KL divergence + linear function

Tags: probability, convex-optimization, information-theory

I am looking at the following problem:
$$
\min_q \underbrace{KL \left[ q(x) ~||~ p(x) \right]}_{=: A} + \underbrace{\mathbb{E}_{x \sim q} \left [ f(x) \right ]}_{=: B}.
$$
For $A$, the solution is $q(x) = p(x)$. For $B$, the solution is a point mass/dirac/delta distribution putting all its mass at $arg,\min f(x)$. Further I know that $A$ should be strictly convex (accd to a comment in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2743771/is-the-kullback-leibler-divergence-strictly-convex-in-both-p-and-q) .)

My questions are the following:

Is there any hope of finding the minimizer in closed form, making use of the two respective solutions? Something like "the minimizer lies on a line between the two respective solutions." ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a case of a variational problem with a subsidiary condition (constraint). The objective is to minimize the functional
$$
J[q]\triangleq \int_x F(q) dx,
$$

where $F(q) \triangleq q(x)\left(\log \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} + f(x)\right)$, under the condition
$$
\tag{1}
\int_x q(x)dx =1.
$$

From [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations), a necessary condition for the function $q(x)$ to be an extremal of $J[q]$ is

$$
\tag{2}
\frac{\partial}{\partial q} F + \lambda =0,
$$
for some constant $\lambda$. Solving the differential equation of (2) with respect to $q(x)$ gives

$$
q(x) = p(x) e^{-f(x) - \lambda -1}.
$$

Plugging this into (1), shows that $\lambda= \log \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p}\left(e^{-f(x)}\right) - 1$, finally resulting in

$$
q(x) = \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}_{x\sim p}\left(e^{-f(x)}\right)} p(x) e^{-f(x)}.
$$

edit1: corrected link.

edit 2: fixed algebraic error, identified by @Artemy.

Comment: Thanks! Can you recommend a resource to get into calculus of variations?

Comment: @bayer I am only familiar with [this](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486414485.html) book, which is very good. But there is a huge literature out there, maybe an expert in the topic (I am not!) could suggest something better.

Comment: Would you please explain the difference between equation (2) and the Euler-Langrange equation?

Comment: @robit Check [this](https://books.google.gr/books?id=YkFLGQeGRw4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q&f=false) reference (Theorem 1, page 43)

Comment: I have a follow up question–I have been trying to find out if your answer also holds for the multivariate case where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. The resource you pointed to does not go into that. Do you have an idea or a direction to look for this?

Answer (score 6):

There is also a way to derive the answer without calculus of variations. First, rewrite
\begin{align}
KL(q(X) \Vert p(X)) + \mathbb{E}_q[f(X)] &= \sum_x q(x) \ln \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} + \sum_x q(x) f(x) \\
& = \sum_x q(x) \ln \frac{q(x)}{p(x)e^{-f(x)}} \tag{1}
\end{align}

Now define the probability distribution $w(x) := \frac{1}{Z} p(x)e^{-f(x)}$, where $Z=\sum_x p(x)e^{-f(x)}$ is the normalization constant. We can then rewrite $(1)$ as
\begin{align}
\sum_x q(x) \ln \frac{q(x)}{w(x)Z} = KL(q(X)\Vert w(X))-\ln Z\tag{2}
\end{align}
Note that $\ln Z$ is a constant that doesn't depend on $q$. Thus, Eq. $(2)$ is minimized by taking $q(x)=w(x)$, at which point it reaches its minimum value of $-\ln Z$.